# Disable ajax in Iframe?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am working on a project where the user can style his/her page.
How can ajax be disabled without disabling javascript in Iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out "Disabling Javascript inside an iframe" at the bottom of this page http://www.iframehtml.com/iframe-scripts.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure I understand what you're trying to do. If you're writing the page sure you can control what JavaScript is executed?

To disable JavaScript try something like..http://javascript.about.com/library/bldis.htm

Hope that helps

Sam